# does a void function prevent a memory leak even if I declare memory on the heap?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am currently studying C++ from a textbook, and according to the author, this code does not cause a memory leak, despite the fact that when I asked ChatGPT, which told me otherwise. The code is simple and is the following:

```cpp
#include<iostream>

void FuncOne() {
    // this is created on the free store?
    // even after the function is finished, the memory is still there.. (I assume)
    int* pVar = new int(5);
    std::cout << "the value of *pVar is:" << *pVar;
}

int main() {
    FuncOne();
    std::system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

`*pVar` should cause a memory leak since there is no `delete` on it? Could perhaps someone explain to me if there is something that I am missing or if it's a simple mistake from the author?

Any explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: Of course it leaks memory. Which textbook said it doesn't?

Comment: A few things. printing `*pVar` is technical UB because the int array isn't initialized. The memory leak has nothing to do with the fact the function returns nothing (void).

Comment: @doug it's not an array.

Comment: @JaMiT and everyone, it's an exercise that said fix the memory leak, and the code stated in the question was the answer. Probably just a simple mistake from the author

Comment: I've updated the question to make the claim better-sourced. Another improvement would be to give the book's title (in the question) so that the next person with the same question is more likely to find this.

Comment: Which book? Have you searched for a later published errata list?

Comment: In the **Sams Teach Yourself C++ in 21 Days** (5th ed) by Jesse Liberty & Bradley Jones, it points out that there is a memory leak, and you shouldn't leak memory your own programs.  p837 shows the function with the memory leak fixed.

Comment: @jthill Good catch. Makes the first part of my comment an error. My brain just processed an initialized int as an array of uninitialized ints. Duh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler can optimize out the statement `int* pVar = new int(5);` applying the as-if rule and producing the resulting function

```
void FuncOne() {
    cout << "the value of *pVar is:" << 5;
}
```

That does not have a memory leak: https://godbolt.org/z/38TfqaPfc

If you disable the optimization, it leaks https://godbolt.org/z/8ojhjdP4q:

```
=================================================================
==1==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks
Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fcf8c2f9518 in operator new(unsigned long) (/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-13.2.0/lib64/libasan.so.8+0xdb518) (BuildId: 5ce9c09d3612315d01d50bcaafaea176e7ddab77)
    #1 0x4011e1 in FuncOne() /app/example.cpp:10
    #2 0x4011be in main /app/example.cpp:5
    #3 0x7fcf8bc29d8f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x29d8f) (BuildId: a43bfc8428df6623cd498c9c0caeb91aec9be4f9)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

But technically, the program has a memory leak - the code allocates and does not delete a resource, you should not rely on optimizations and expect that they fix memory leaks.

Comment: Although the answer provided by user **"273K"** is correct, it is false if your call new on an object that has side effects when constructed. It is always good practice to code in a manner that does not relies on compiler optimizations to achieve what you want. And it is good practice to code without causing memory leaks in the first place. I have a game engine of my own and I call ```new GameObject()``` in all sorts of functions and I've never seen it been optimized away; not even in ```Release``` mode.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto How did you observe that none was optimized away? Why are you calling `new` at all?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I did not say anything leading anyone to believe that I did not notice the optimization. Perhaps you should read more carefully before assuming things with such questions.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto _"I call `new GameObject()` in all sorts of functions and I've never seen it been optimized away"_ - This is what I was asking about.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The key is "function side effects" or "constructor side effects". For example, if you call new on a class that adds itself to an ```std::vector```, it will not get optimized away if that ```std::vector``` is used in other parts of your program.

Comment: @ChristopherBarriosAgosto Sure, the compiler must follow the as-if rule, so how is 273Ks answer false? You said _"if you call new on an object that has side effects ..."_ - and what does that have to do with the answer which clearly states what the compiler is allowed to do in the very case OP is asking about. It also says that _"But technically, the program has a memory leak ..."_. I don't get where your objection comes from.

Answer (score 4):

> `*pVar` should cause a memory leak since there is no `delete` on it?

Yes, that's exactly what happens.